# My C# functions seems to be acting as if I am passing by ref, why does it do this?

Tags: c#, function, ref

I have a boolean that returns true or false after looking at some boolean arrays and ints.

```
if (CheckForRoute(VertWallAbove, HoriWallLeft, NewWallX, NewWallY, NewWallHor))
```

During this function the parameter that comes from HoriWallLeft has its value[0,0] set to true (Prior to this every value in the array is false and I have checked this is happening with breakpoints). immediately after exiting the function the value of HoriWallLeft[0,0] is true, I would've thought this would only happen if I am passing by ref.

Edit:
Here is an example of what I mean

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool[] Test = new bool[] { false, false, false, false };
    ExampleFunction(Test);
    if(Test[0])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
    else
    {
    Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
static bool ExampleFunction(bool[] TestArray)
{
    TestArray[0] = true;
    return true;
}
```

I would expect this to output B but it outputs A

Comment: So, you're basically passing a pointer to an array of booleans. That's why you can modify individual elements.

Comment: arrays are reference-types. Doing anything on one reference is reflected in all other references to the same array-instance.

Comment: Arrays are a reference type so the modification to TestArray[0] is actually applied to the array object to which it refers.

Comment: @LittleSweetSeas - Your comment is misleading.  The bool[] is not passed by reference unless the `ref` keyword is used.  In the example code, it is passed by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct, you are passing a reference to this array to the Function. 
There is no copy of the array created.

If you want a copy to be created, you could call

```
ExampleFunction(Test.ToArray());
```

Comment: Does this change if it is a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: No, it would only change if you use ExampleFunction(bool b1, bool b2, bool b3). Bool is a value type, any array is a reference type. Your Test variable is a reference to an Array already; not the array itself. This is important to know when defining a readonly bool[] array. Here it's also only the reference that is readonly, not the values of the array.